# How do I run the OpenId4Java app engine sample app?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, openid4java

OpenId4Java have an appengine-consumer in their sample code. However I while I can build the sample I can't figure out how to run it. mvn jetty:run fails and there doesn't seem another obvious start mechanism.

I'm developing my other projects using the maven gae plugin and start them with either mvn gae:run or via the IntelliJ AppEngine application config.

So how do I run the sample app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the README file inside `appengine-consumer` sample,

> First, create the WAR directory:
>
> $ mvn package
>
> Now, test the server locally:
>
> $ $PATH_TO_APPENGINE/dev_appserver.sh -a  -p 8080 \
>   target/appengine-consumer
>
> Point your browser to http://:8080 to test.

Comment: I've given you a point because you've pointed me the doc that is meant to sort it for me. Seems like the example itself is busted. I had to add a bunch of stuff to the POM to get it to build and when I finally deploy it it still complains of missing classes.